# Por que o código retorna NaN noi cálculo de IMC?

Tags: javascript, html, formulário

Não sei o que está ocorrendo, mas o que acontece é que ele retorna "NaN". O código é para ser um cálculo de IMC simples.

Ele supostamente pega os valores dos inputs de um form e realiza as operações.
Caso necessário, o HTML.

```js
var peso = parseDouble(document.getElementById('inPeso'));
var altura = parseDouble(document.getElementById('inAlt'));
var aux = 0, c = 0;


function calcImc(){
    aux = altura * altura;
    c = peso/aux;
    alert("O IMC é " + c);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> IMC</title>
        <meta carset = "utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="imc.css"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="6551sans.ico"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="IMC.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Calcule seu IMC</h1>
        <form method="GET" id="formulario">
            <label>Peso</label>
            <input id ="inPeso" type="text" placeholder="Insira seu peso" size="20" maxlength="5">
            <label>Altura</label>
            <input id ="inAlt" type="text" placeholder="Insira sua altura (Ex.: 1.7)" size="25" maxlength="5">
            <label>Sexo</label>
            <input type="radio" class="inSexo" name="sexo" value ="m">
            <label>Masculino</label>
            <input type="radio" class="inSexo" name="sexo" value ="f">
            <label>Feminino</label>
            <button type="submit" accesskey="e" onclick="calcImc();">Calcular</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está multiplicando elementos HTML, você deve pegar o valor deles.

```
function calcImc(){
    // adicione o .value para cada elemento selecionado conforme as linhas abaixo
    let peso = document.getElementById('inPeso').value;
    let altura = document.getElementById('inAlt').value;
    let aux = 0, c = 0;

    aux = altura * altura;
    c = peso/aux;
    alert("O IMC é " + c);
}
```

Comment: Para multiplicação ou divisão, não é necessário converter o número. Com isso, o parseFloat usado é desnecessário.

Answer (score 5):

Tem alguns problemas no código. Primeiro está declarando e inicializando as variáveis fora da função, isto não faz sentido, além de ser ruim por manter escopo global acaba sendo executado em momento inadequando onde não tem valores para pegar. Depois não está pegando o valor contido no elemento, está pegando o elemento como um todo, tem que pegar o valor com a propriedade `value`, e aí não precisa nem converter (e se tivesse, `parseDouble()` não existe). Aproveitei e simplifiquei o código. Faça o teste.

```js
function calcImc() {
    var peso = document.getElementById('inPeso').value;
    var altura = document.getElementById('inAlt').value;
    alert("O IMC é " + (peso / (altura * altura)));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> IMC</title>
        <meta carset = "utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="imc.css"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="6551sans.ico"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="IMC.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Calcule seu IMC</h1>
        <form method="GET" id="formulario">
            <label>Peso</label>
            <input id ="inPeso" type="text" placeholder="Insira seu peso" size="20" maxlength="5">
            <label>Altura</label>
            <input id ="inAlt" type="text" placeholder="Insira sua altura (Ex.: 1.7)" size="25" maxlength="5">
            <label>Sexo</label>
            <input type="radio" class="inSexo" name="sexo" value ="m">
            <label>Masculino</label>
            <input type="radio" class="inSexo" name="sexo" value ="f">
            <label>Feminino</label>
            <button type="submit" accesskey="e" onclick="calcImc();">Calcular</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/LocalVar.js).